# Get Key names and Values names from JSON and use in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, highcharts

I have a JSON file with the following structure:

JSON Structure:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1536700,
        "title": "final_output",
        "error": "",
        "data": [
            {
                "metric": 4940616.0,
                "title": "d_revenue"
            },
            {
                "metric": 5132162.0,
                "title": "p_revenue"
            },
            {
                "metric": 4954576.0,
                "title": "s_revenue"
            },
            {
                "metric": 4882217.0,
                "title": "u_revenue"
            },
            {
                "metric": 4869609.0,
                "title": "t_revenue"
            },
            {
                "metric": 5075422.0,
                "title": "w_revenue"
            },
            {
                "metric": 4461996.0,
                "title": "v_revenue"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Next Structure:

```
[
    {
        "run_id": 1536700,
        "code_title": "select_data",
        "error": "",
        "data": [
            {
                "user_name": "C_51",
                "num1": 51,
                "num2": 101,
                "num3": 151
            },
            {
                "user_name": "H_51",
                "num1": 51,
                "num2": 101,
                "num3": 151
            },
            {
                "user_name": "C_52",
                "num1": 52,
                "num2": 102,
                "num3": 152
            },
            {
                "user_name": "H_52",
                "num1": 52,
                "num2": 102,
                "num3": 152
            },
            {
                "user_name": "C_53",
                "num1": 53,
                "num2": 103,
                "num3": 153
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to get the keys inside `data` and then decide what the x-axis would be and what the y-axis would be and I wanted to do something like http://jsfiddle.net/k32a59vL/1/.

THis is my code:

```
    $.getJSON(api, function(elem) {
        console.log(elem);
        elem.forEach(d => {

        });
    });
```

The `console.log(elem)` gives me the json structure mentioned above. How do I just get `metric and title` from the first structure and `user_name, num1, num2, num3`. How do I get those values?

Comment: its unclear what you want to achieve. Please clearly tell what is the problem ,what are the inputs and what are the expected outputs....

Comment: @Supercool. , data is my input and it can be different. I just want to be able to get the common keys. For example for the first json structure, I want to get `metric, title` and for the second I want to return `user_name, num1, num2, num3`

Comment: is that it or do you have any other problem??

Comment: and inside data array ....will the objects contain different keys or same keys like one object has key1,key2,key3 ,other object in the same array has key1,key2 only ...does this match your scenario?

Comment: @Supercool. , Inside each json structure, inside data, they will be the same. I want to get those and eventually use those values in highcharts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Object.keys(yourObject) to get the keys

```
 $.getJSON(api, function(elem) {
      let keys=elem.map( structure =>  Object.keys(structure.data[0]))         
   });
```

Run the following snippet to check if it works

```js
 let ele= [{"id": 1536700,"title": "final_output","error": "",
"data": [{"metric": 4940616.0,"title": "d_revenue"},{"metric": 5132162.0,"title": "p_revenue"},{"metric":4954576.0,"title": "s_revenue"},{"metric": 4882217.0,"title":"u_revenue"},{"metric": 4869609.0,"title":"t_revenue"},{"metric": 5075422.0,"title": "w_revenue"},{"metric": 4461996.0,"title": "v_revenue"}
]
},
{"run_id": 1536700,"code_title": "select_data","error": "",
  "data": [{"user_name": "C_51","num1": 51,"num2": 101,"num3": 151},{"user_name": "H_51","num1": 51,"num2": 101, "num3": 151},{"user_name": "C_52","num1": 52,"num2": 102,"num3": 152},{"user_name": "H_52","num1": 52,"num2": 102,"num3":152},{"user_name": "C_53","num1": 53,"num2": 103,"num3": 153}
]}]
 console.log(ele.map( structure =>  Object.keys(structure.data[0])))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```